# Javascript/jQuery Append to FormData() returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do a simple file upload using jQuery. I have a file input in my HTML like so:

```
<form id="PhotoUploadForm" action="/some/correct/url" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" id="uploadPhoto" accept="image">
</form>
```

I also have some JavaScript / jQuery bound to the change event of the input, like so:

```
   $('#uploadPhoto').on("change", function (event) {

        var fileData = this.files[0];
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('image',fileData);
        data.append('content','What could go wrong');
        console.log(data.image, data.content); // this outputs 'undefined undefined' in the console

        $.ajax ({
            url: "/some/correct/url",
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
               console.log('about to send');
            },
            success: function ( response ) {                   
                console.log( 'now do something!' )
            },
            error: function ( response ) {
                console.log("response failed");
            }
        });
    });
```

I noticed I was getting a 500 error! Most likely the data is incorrect, I know the URL is good. So I tried to output the data to the console and I noticed that my data appends return '`undefined`'

```
console.log(data.image, data.content); // this outputs 'undefined undefined' in the console
```

when I console.log(data) I get the following:

```
FormData {append: function}__proto__: FormData
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Why are `data.image` & `data.content` undefined? When I output the `this.files[0]` I get the following:

```
File {webkitRelativePath: "", lastModified: 1412680079000, lastModifiedDate: Tue Oct 07 2014 13:07:59 GMT+0200 (CEST), name: "2575-Web.jpg", type: "image/jpeg"…}lastModified: 1412680079000lastModifiedDate: Tue Oct 07 2014 13:07:59 GMT+0200 (CEST)name: "2575-Web.jpg"size: 138178type: "image/jpeg"webkitRelativePath: ""__proto__: File
```

So the issue isn't with the image. Am I correct?

Comment: i think 2nd line should be `var fileData = $(this).files[0];`

Comment: Can you inspect what is the content type of the request in the Network tab of the web inspector?

Comment: Ah, good thinking, it says 'application'

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird nope, it is good "as is". `$(this).files[0]` will cause error.

Comment: set `contentType: false` in the ajax request so that jQuery will set it properly

Comment: FormData will be supported only in the latest browser version. Can you just share your browser version.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Issue

You are misunderstanding the `FormData` object. A `FormData` object has only an `.append()` method, which **doesn't append properties to it**, but only stores the data provided. Hence, obviously, the `.image` and `.content` properties will be undefined.

If you want to create a object with the `.image` and `.content` properties you should instead create a regular object and then send it.

## Workaround

To achieve what you want you have some options:

1. Using `FormData`:

   - Call its constructor passing the `<form>` element as an argument, and it will do all the work for you.
   - OR: create the object and then use the `.append()` method.
2. Use a regular object and send it.
3. Use a regular object, convert it to JSON and send it using `contentType: 'application/json'`.

**What option would you choose?** It only **depends on the back-end**. If you are developing the back-end make sure you are retrieving the data from the `POST` request in the correct way, otherwise check the site and see what kind of data you'll need to send.

### Option 1

Create the `FormData` object:

- Method 1, let the constructor work for you:

  ```
  var form = document.getElementById("PhotoUploadForm"),
      myData = new FormData(form);
  ```
- Method 2, do it by yourself:

  ```
  var fileData = this.files[0],
      myData = new FormData();

  myData.append('image', fileData);
  ```

Then, later in your code, you can send it:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/some/correct/url",
    type: 'POST',
    data: myData, // here it is
    ...
});
```

### Option 2

Create a regular object and send it:

```
var myData = {
        image: this.files[0]
    };

$.ajax({
    url: "/some/correct/url",
    type: 'POST',
    data: myData, // here it is
    ...
});
```

### Option 3

```
var myData = {
        image: this.files[0]
    };

myData = JSON.stringify(myData); // convert to JSON

$.ajax({
    url: "/some/correct/url",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: myData, // here it is
    ...
});
```